# Cannot reinitialise DataTable using jquery /laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I have the following datatable:

```
   <table id="projets_table" class="data-table data-table-feature">
        <thead>
            <tr> 
                <th>Numéro de projet</th>
                <th>Client</th>
                <th>Agence de conseil</th>
                <th>Agence de production</th>
                <th>Agence de casting</th>
                <th>Date de tournage</th>
                <th>Date de première diffusion</th>
                <th>Payé</th>
                <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
```

And I'm getting the data from database by using the following script which displays the data into datatable using server side processing:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function(){

 if (!$.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('.data-table-feature')) {
  $('.data-table-feature').DataTable({


     destroy: true,
     orderCellsTop: true,
     retrieve: true,
     processing: true,
     serverSide: true,

  ajax:{

     url: "{{ route('projets.getdata') }}",

    },

     columns:[
    
     {
      data:'numero_projet',
      name: 'numero_projet'
     },
      {
      data: 'client',
      name: 'client'
     },
      {
      data: 'agence_conseil',
      name: 'agence_conseil'
     },
      {
      data: 'agence_production',
      name: 'agence_production'
     },
     {
      data: 'agence_casting',
      name: 'agence_casting'
     },
      {
      data: 'date_tournage',
      name: 'date_tournage'
     },
      {
      data: 'date_premiere_diffusion',
      name: 'date_premiere_diffusion'
     },
      {
      data: 'paye',
      name: 'paye'
     },
     {
      data: 'action',
      name: 'action',
      orderable: false
     }
    ]
    
    } );
   
   }
});

</script>
```

But I'm getting the following error in alert :

> DataTables warning: table id=projets_table - Cannot reinitialise DataTable. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/3

What is wrong with my code? I don't know what is the problem exactly.

If you have any idea I will be grateful, please help

Answer (score 0):

Your DataTable initialisation has both the **retrive** and **destroy** options. As shown in screenshot below, from the Official Docs, these options cannot be used together. Try using any one alone.

[image]

Comment: thank you for your answer , but that does not resolve my problem